# How to write a predicate minmax(L, X, Y)?

Tags: prolog

How to write a predicate minmax(L, X, Y) to find out min value of X and max value of Y in list of integer L.

Example:

```
?- minmax([1, -10, 1, 0, 7, 7], X, Y).
X = -10, Y = 7.
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's define `list_minnum_maxnum/3` like [`list_minnum/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31722246/4609915):

```
list_minnum_maxnum([E|Es],Min,Max) :-
   V is E,
   list_minnum0_minnum_maxnum0_maxnum(Es,V,Min,V,Max).

list_minnum0_minnum_maxnum0_maxnum([]    ,Min ,Min,Max ,Max).
list_minnum0_minnum_maxnum0_maxnum([E|Es],Min0,Min,Max0,Max) :-
   V    is E,
   Min1 is min(Min0,V),
   Max1 is max(Max0,V),
   list_minnum0_minnum_maxnum0_maxnum(Es,Min1,Min,Max1,Max).
```

Sample query as given by the OP:

```
?- list_minnum_maxnum([1,-10,1,0,7,7], Min,Max).
Min = -10,
Max = 7.
```

Note that this implementation of `list_minnum_maxnum/3` works with all kinds of numbers.

```
?- list_minnum_maxnum([1,-10,1,0,7.2,7,7], Min,Max).
Min = -10,
Max = 7.2.
```

---

If you only care about handling integers, **use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define `list_zmin_zmax/3` as follows:

```
list_zmin_zmax([E|Es],Min,Max) :-
   V #= E,
   list_zmin0_zmin_zmax0_zmax(Es,V,Min,V,Max).

list_zmin0_zmin_zmax0_zmax([]    ,Min ,Min,Max ,Max).
list_zmin0_zmin_zmax0_zmax([E|Es],Min0,Min,Max0,Max) :-
   V    #= E,
   Min1 #= min(Min0,V),
   Max1 #= max(Max0,V),
   list_zmin0_zmin_zmax0_zmax(Es,Min1,Min,Max1,Max).
```

Same sample use as before:

```
?- list_zmin_zmax([1,-10,1,0,7,7], Min,Max).
Min = -10,
Max = 7.
```

OK! What about support for non-integer numbers?

```
?- list_zmin_zmax([1,-10,1,0,7.2,7,7], Min,Max).
ERROR: Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found `7.2'
```

We expected getting an error, we got an error...

Note that thanks to [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), we can run more general queries, too!

```
?- list_zmin_zmax([A,B], Min,Max).
A #>= Min, Max #>= A, Min #= min(A,B),
B #>= Min, Max #>= B, Max #= max(A,B).
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted, you need to iterate over the list, *accumulating* the min and max values as you go. So, assuming that you have to write this from scratch, the first thing you need to do is *decompose* the problem into simple steps:

1. You need a means of comparing two objects and determine which is the lower or higher.
2. You need a means of iterating over the loop and tracking the min and max values seen as you go.

That leads to a `min/3` and  `max/3`, thus:

```
min(X,X,X).
min(X,Y,X) :- X < Y .
min(X,Y,Y) :- X > Y .

max(X,X,X).
max(X,Y,X) :- X > Y .
max(X,Y,Y) :- X < Y .
```

For your purposes here, one could even combine them into a single predicate, if you liked:

```
rank( X , X , X , X ) .
rank( X , Y , X , Y ) :- X < Y .
rank( X , Y , Y , X ) :- X > Y .
```

A pretty typical programming *pattern* in Prolog is to have a simple public API predicate that invokes a private "worker" predicate that does the actual work. Often the worker predicate will carry temporary "accumulator" variables that simplify the job. Your public predicate might look like:

```
minmax([X|Xs],Min,Max) :- minmax_scan( Xs , X , X , Min , Max ).
```

Here, your public API predicate accepts a non-empty list, seeding the min/max accumulators the worker predicate uses with the head of the list, then calling the worker predicate with the tail of the list.

Your worker predicate then might look like this:

```
% if the list is empty, we've solved the puzzle, right?
minmax_scan( [] , Min , Max , Min , Max ) .
% if the list is non-empty, we need to compare its head to
% the current value for min/max to determine the new values for min/max
% (which might be the same), and then recurse down on the tail of the list
minmax_scan( [X|Xs] , CurrMin , CurrMax , Min , Max ) :-
  min( X , CurrMin , NextMin ) ,
  max( X , CurrMax , NextMax ) ,
  minmax_scan( Xs , NextMin , NextMax , Min , Max )
  .
```

Easy!

Answer (score 1):

take the first value from the list, then examine each other element of the list, selecting lower/higher values as temporary min/max.

When at the end of list, you have both...

```
minmax([First|Rest], Min, Max) :-
   minmax(Rest, First, First, Min, Max).

minmax([], Min, Max, Min, Max).
minmax([Value|Ns], MinCurr, MaxCurr, Min, Max) :-
   .... 
   minmax(Ns, MinNext, MaxNext, Min, Max).
```

I'll let you write the tests before the recursive call (i.e. fill the dots!)

*edit* just to point out library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)), available in several Prolog systems:

```
1 ?- [user].
minmax(L, X, Y) :- aggregate( (min(E), max(E)), member(E, L), (X, Y) ).
|: 
true.

2 ?- minmax([1, -10, 1, 0, 7, 7], X, Y).
X = -10,
Y = 7.
```

Comment: The version using `library(aggregate)` impressed me. However, it shows spurious behavior in corner cases: the goal `minmax([1+1],1+1,2)` succeeds, but the goals `minmax([1+1],2,2)`, `minmax([1+1],1+1,1+1)`, `minmax([1+1],2,1+1)` all fail.

Comment: @repeat: I originally posted the answer as most instructive for a beginner. Extending the behaviour would require to 'eval' each member, and take the result where needed: `, (member(M, L), E is M), `. But aggregate/3 it's meant to solve problems that were not easy to solve in plain Prolog, and is itself not obvious to implement. The library is rather convoluted.

Comment: Ok. Actually, explicit evaluation is only required for the first list item, not the other ones, as every result of `is` is  a number anyway... Apart from that, it may also improve runtime if the re-evaluation of complex expressions is avoided.

Comment: Sometimes I like using arithmetic expressions on the "caller" side, but I still have to find a proper way of documenting these "often-hidden" features. Do you have ideas?

Comment: @repeat: no, sorry. The 'functional side' of Prolog is historically rather weak. I tried myself, with term rewriting in my 'lifter' (maybe, an [interesting post](http://swi-prolog.996271.n3.nabble.com/Renaming-map-gt-dict-class-gt-type-td13585i20.html#a13742) sorted out of old SWI-Prolog mailing list)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something convoluted and a bit complex.

```
is_minmax(A,B-D,C-E) :-
    D is min(...),
    E is max(...) .

pair(A,B,A-B).

minmax(L,MIN,MAX) :- 
    L=[A|_], length(L,N), N2 is N-1,
    length(L2,N2), append(L2,[MIN],L22), 
    length(L3,N2), append(L3,[MAX],L33),
    maplist(pair, [A|L2], L22, KL2),
    maplist(pair, [A|L3], L33, KL3),
    maplist(is_minmax, L, KL2, KL3).
```

(works in SWI Prolog). Try to figure out what to write in place of dots `...`.