# Excluding all occurrences of the minimum number in a list

Tags: list, prolog

As a Prolog newbie, I try to define a predicate `filter_min/2` which takes two lists to determine if the second list is the same as the first, but with all occurrences of the minimum number removed.

Sample queries with expected results:

```
?- filter_min([3,2,7,8], N).
N = [3,7,8].

?- filter_min([3,2,7,8], [3,7,8]).
true.
```

I tried but I always get the same result: `false`. I don't know what the problem is. I need help!

Here is my code:

```
filter_min(X,Y) :-
    X == [],
    write("ERROR: List parameter is empty!"),
    !;
    min_list(X,Z),
    filter(X,Y,Z).

filter([],[],0).
filter([H1|T1],[H2|T2],Z) :-
    \+ number(H1),
    write("ERROR: List parameter contains a non-number element"),
    !;
    H1 \= Z -> H2 is H1, filter(T1,T2,Z);
    filter(T1,T2,Z).
```

Comment: What if the minimum occurs more than once in the given list, like in `[3,2,7,2,8,2]`?

Comment: @repeat the result should still be [3,7,8], I think.

Comment: in SWI-Prolog, `filter_min(L,N) :- min_list(L,M),delete(L,M,N).`, but @Fatalize answer is better if you are going to learn Prolog

Comment: Promise: Will put a bounty for a pure solution that terminates for (certain) cases where neither the length of the first nor of the second argument is known. (Please remind me should I forget it, these 48h time spans are pretty long)

Comment: @false. Please provide more information on the particular solution you seek with the bounty: Does it have to deal with floats (and other non-integer numbers), too? May it use [tag:prolog-coroutining]? May it use / should it use [tag:clpfd]? What about determinism? Do you mean "pure from the outside" when you demand a "pure" solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- `filter([],[],0).` will not unify when working with any list that does not have 0 as its minimum value, which is not what you want. You want it to unify regardless of the minimum value to end your recursion.
- The way you wrote `filter([H1|T1],[H2|T2],Z)` and its body will make it so that the two lists always have the same number of elements, when in fact the second one should have at least one less.

A correct implementation of `filter/3` would be the following:

```
filter([],[],_).
filter([H1|T1],L2,Z):-
    \+ number(H1),
    write("ERROR: List parameter contains a non-number element"),
    !;
    H1 \= Z -> filter(T1,T2,Z), L2 = [H1|T2];
    filter(T1,L2,Z).
```

Comment: you are right, filter([],[],0) does't make sense. I find another question, I call function `min_list `  before ` \+number` so I will get an error before goes to my own error check. Is there any way for me to check and stop before call the `min` function.

Comment: @G_cy you can use [`min_member(X,Min)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=min_member/2) before min_list, and check that `number(Min)` is true, before calling min_list. Don't forget to accept this answer if this solved your problems

Comment: `E = 2, filter([1],[1],E).` succeeds, but `filter([1],[1],E), E = 2.` incorrectly fails. It should: either succeed, or produce an instantiation error, or (not here, but in principle) loop.

Comment: @false Adding the rule `filter([],L,_) :- L \= [], !.` fixes the case were the number to remove is not in the first list. The case where the second list is longer than the first list can easily be taken care of by failing if the length of the second list is longer than the length of the first list.

Comment: I cannot see what your suggested fix would improve: You either need an instantiation error or correct success

Answer (score 3):

A bounty was offered...

> ... for a pure solution that terminates for (certain) cases where neither the length of the first nor of the second argument is known.

Here's a candidate implementation handling integer values, built on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

filter_min(Xs,Ys) :-
   filter_min_picked_gt(Xs,_,false,Ys).

filter_min_picked_gt([]    ,_,true  ,[]).
filter_min_picked_gt([Z|Xs],M,Picked,[Z|Zs]) :-
   Z #> M,
   filter_min_picked_gt(Xs,M,Picked,Zs).
filter_min_picked_gt([M|Xs],M,_,Zs) :-
   filter_min_picked_gt(Xs,M,true,Zs).
```

Some sample queries:

```
?- filter_min([3,2,7,8],[3,7,8]).
true ; false.                        % correct, but leaves choicepoint

?- filter_min([3,2,7,8],Zs).
Zs = [3,7,8] ; false.                % correct, but leaves choicepoint
```

Now, some queries terminate even though both list lengths are unknown:

```
?- filter_min([2,1|_],[1|_]).
false.                               % terminates

?- filter_min([1,2|_],[3,2|_]).
false.                               % terminates
```

Note that the implementation doesn't *always* finitely fail (terminate) in cases that are logically false:

```
?- filter_min([1,2|_],[2,1|_]).      % does _not_ terminate
```

Comment: @false. Indeed, but I see no alternative to meeting the bounty-objective.

Comment: It is not only choice-point un-friendly but leads to all kinds of anomalous behaviour for lists like `[0*1,1*0,-1,-1*1]`

Comment: `filter_min([1,2,3,4],[3,2,4]).` fails but `filter_min([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4]).` succeeds?

Comment: @Will: But that's a feature!

Comment: @WillNess. The OP stated "takes two lists to determine if the second list is the same as the first, but with all occurrences of the minimum number removed."

Comment: @repeat ah,  so "same" meant with ordering too, not only membership. OK, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, we can get the minimum number using the predicate [`list_minnum/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=min_list/2):

```
?- list_minnum([3,2,7,8],M).
M = 2.
```

We can define `list_minnum/2` like this:

```
list_minnum([E|Es],M) :-
   V is E,
   list_minnum0_minnum(Es,V,M).

list_minnum0_minnum([],M,M).
list_minnum0_minnum([E|Es],M0,M) :-
   M1 is min(E,M0),
   list_minnum0_minnum(Es,M1,M).
```

For the sake of completeness, here's the super-similar `list_maxnum/2`:

```
list_maxnum([E|Es],M) :-
   V is E,
   list_maxnum0_maxnum(Es,V,M).

list_maxnum0_maxnum([],M,M).
list_maxnum0_maxnum([E|Es],M0,M) :-
   M1 is max(E,M0),
   list_maxnum0_maxnum(Es,M1,M).
```

Next, we use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915) in tandem with  [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) to exclude **all** occurrences of `M`:

```
?- M=2, tfilter(dif(M),[2,3,2,7,2,8,2],Xs).
Xs = [3,7,8].
```

Put the two steps together and define `min_excluded/2`:

```
min_excluded(Xs,Ys) :-
   list_minnum(Xs,M),
   tfilter(dif(M),Xs,Ys).
```

Let's run some queries!

```
?- min_excluded([3,2,7,8],Xs).
Xs = [3,7,8].

?- min_excluded([3,2,7,8,2],Xs).
Xs = [3,7,8].
```

Comment: ~ : `min_list/2` is not very pure

Comment: Also the argument order/name is bad. `list_min` would be better.

Comment: I'm not sure a "newbie in Prolog" is looking for a solution that uses meta-predicates for such a simple task.

Comment: @Fatalize.  Granted. OTOH, meta-predicates enable people to solve the task at hand **before** they master the ins-and-outs of recursion.

Comment: @Fatalize: Can you provide a solution that gives correct answers and does not use meta-predicates? This would be a constructive contribution.

Comment: Its just an ill-defined predicate. Consider: `min_list([1+1],Y).` succeeds with `Y = 1+1` but `min_list([1+1,1+1],Y).` succeeds with `Y = 2`.

Comment: Why do you insist on `min_excluded([X,Y],Zs)` to produce an instantiation errror? It could produce clean and correct answers! (At least when restricting one to integers)

Comment: @false.  U r right! OTOH I wasn't sure if the OP was dealing with integers, or with floats, too.

Comment: @repeat element in the first list should be a number. integers, floats, or others. It should not be a string.

Answer (score 2):

For a Prolog newbie, better start with the basics. The following works when first argument is fully instantiated, and the second is an uninstantiated variable, computing the result in one pass over the input list.

```
% remmin( +From, -Result). 

% remmin([],[]).              % no min elem to remove from empty list
remmin([A|B], R):- 
  remmin(B, A, [A], [], R).   % remove A from B to get R, keeping [A]
                              % in case a smaller elem will be found

remmin([C|B], A, Rev, Rem, R):-  
  C > A -> remmin(B, A, [C|Rev], [C|Rem], R) ;
  C==A  -> remmin(B, A, [C|Rev],    Rem,  R) ;
  C < A -> remmin(B, C, [C|Rev],    Rev,  R).

remmin([], _, _, Rem, R) :- reverse(Rem, R).
```